# Having trouble finding the error in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Given a MongoDB database with two collections, `Movies` and `Actors`, write a query to find all of the genres that have more than 23 movies.

Your output should contain only the name of genre (rename it as "name")

Movies collection: each Movie has its unique id (`$movie_id`), name (`$movie_name`), country (`$country`), director (`$director`), releasing date (`$release_year`), ratings (`$ratings`), genre (`$genre`), and `$actors` [an array of actor id (`$actor_id`)].

Every movie is associated with only one genre and one director.

first, I want to group by genre, then count the number of same genre, then select those genres with count>23. But my code isn't working.

```
db.Movies.aggregate(
{$group : {name:"$genre", count:{$sum:1}}},
$match: {count : {$gt : 23}}},
{$project: {name:1, count:0}}
)
```

Comment: Which is it? Mango or Mongo?

Comment: sorry, It's MangoDB.

Comment: Er... It appears to be Mongo.

Comment: Yeah, its Mongo...!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, syntax errors - aggregate function accepts an array. And $group must have _id column for grouping

```
db.Movies.aggregate([
  {$group : {_id:"$genre", count:{$sum:1}}},
  {$match: {count : {$gt : 23}}},
  {$project: {name:"$_id", count:0}}
])
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks! But why did you replace name with _id on the second line?

Comment: Syntax for $group is _id : "$fieldNameYouWantToGroupOn".